# How to make "identity" source map

Tags: javascript, source-maps

### Background

I have a build process that copies JavaScript source files to certain locations.

I can then run it with Node.js.

However, when debugging with VSCode, it doesn't understand the relationship between the source files and the runtime files (and it's more complicated than a single `remoteRoot`).

### Question

My proposed solution is to use a source map to map back to the original file.

How can I make a source map with identical content mapping, but just a change in the file path?

Comment: Your build process should have a way to generate source maps as an artifact of the compile. Generating them by hand is possible but non-trivial as the actual mappings are encoded for brevity. https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/

Comment: @Ouroborus my build process in this case is `cp`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

https://github.com/thibauts/node-generate-source-map

I modified their basic usage example to take filename as a CLI argument `process.argv[2]` and just redirected output to desired *.js.min file.